# Submit transaction in Node js Error 400

Tags: stellar-sdk

I initiated a small node js project in which I installed the sdk module in order to communicate with horizon and try out some things, I am following this [page from the docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/examples.html).

However I getting an error. As far as I understand it comes from this line:

```
const transactionResult = await server.submitTransaction(transaction);
```

Here is the error log(the log is too long so I will just copy paste the first lines:

```
An error has occured:
{ Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/docker_stellar/myserver/myapp/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/home/ubuntu/workspace/docker_stellar/myserver/myapp/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/ubuntu/workspace/docker_stellar/myserver/myapp/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (streamreadable.js:1064:12)
    at combinedTickCallback (internal/process/nexttick.js:139:11)
    at process.tickCallback (internal/process/nexttick.js:181:9)
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 60000,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, /',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Client-Name': 'js-stellar-sdk',
        'X-Client-Version': '0.15.3',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0',
        'Content-Length': 303 },
     method: 'post',
     url: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions',
     data: 'tx=AAAAAMKEdM3SKNa%2BVS2IcCHh0hbJpC9eKFwi%2BzFTRdqph9JMAAAAZAAAQT0AAAADAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFzBqDoAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAACzn9ykXx%2FXpZb2ztFecMWAVIjl3oeMoMzNlQuq2igQ                                                                                           9AAAAAAAAAADQsJmHAAAAAAAAAAGph9JMAAAAQH1pa8aof1o81B7aUJ8XPIKBU%2BDuw%2F9DZLQ7HoS3ueS2RkGlm%2BkUoAQFAi0jmdIsC841ojzyOmMZyjZBo%2BTSEws%3D' },
  request:
   ClientRequest {
     ...
```

Please if anyone has any idea why i'm having this error I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: What does the response say? You've trimmed that part of the error response out, all of this is details about the request you made. Could you replace that with the portion under `response`?

Comment: you mean "error.response" ? here is the log : https://justpaste.it/4ebmj

Answer (score 1):

Your [transaction](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAMKEdM3SKNa%2BVS2IcCHh0hbJpC9eKFwi%2BzFTRdqph9JMAAAAZAAAQT0AAAADAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFzBqDoAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAACzn9ykXx%2FXpZb2ztFecMWAVIjl3oeMoMzNlQuq2igQ9AAAAAAAAAADQsJmHAAAAAAAAAAGph9JMAAAAQH1pa8aof1o81B7aUJ8XPIKBU%2BDuw%2F9DZLQ7HoS3ueS2RkGlm%2BkUoAQFAi0jmdIsC841ojzyOmMZyjZBo%2BTSEws%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test) is a payment to the account [GAWOP5...](https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GAWOP5ZJC7D7L2LFXWZ3IV44GFQBKIRZO6Q6GKBTGNSUF2VWRICD2HZF) which does not exist. You have to [create an account](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#create-account) first before you can send payments to it. (In case you created that account more than a day ago, it's gone because testnet was reset yesterday.)

Error would have stated `op_no_destination`, you can get the relevant error response details like this:

```
try {
  await server.submitTransaction(...)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.response.data.extras);
}
```

Comment: the "error.response.data.extras" said :
{ envelope_xdr: 'AAAAAM8WkMKxiwXaRDFThxR/HF/EPoLIB605jlOOMcJ1DdrUAAAAZAAAeKsAAAACAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFzCuoEAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAFLiXyPotSB1ZNc4r/n7EMYv/BDw/SgCClfRo/eDzVZjAAAAAAAAAADQsJmHAAAAAAAAAAF1DdrUAAAAQBPbIEPaaZJYHvv88S0woMWYHAB6gNYoUxbYDRTlVTvDJ76oE7+7hDGUERE559Uzbco97oMSVBbFJNPxRdyxoQ4=',
  result_codes:
   { transaction: 'tx_failed',
     operations: [ 'op_no_destination' ] },
  result_xdr: 'AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAB////+wAAAAA=' }
But i still dnt understand cuz i recreated the accounts just now !!!

Comment: isn't this [link](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test) for creating test accounts !

Comment: Yeah, but again the recipient [GBJOEXZD5C2SA5LE244K76P3CDDC77AQ6D6SQAQKK7I2H54DZVLGH3GX](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBJOEXZD5C2SA5LE244K76P3CDDC77AQ6D6SQAQKK7I2H54DZVLGH3GX) does not exist. You can't make a payment to an empty account.

Comment: You have to initially fund the recipient too. Either with the laboratory tool or by doing a createAccount instead of a payment operation.

Comment: thanks  !!! i changed the StellarSdk.Operation.payment operation, to StellarSdk.Operation.createAccount, and the error is gone , but now i have a new error : error TypeError: startingBalance argument must be of type String, represent a positive number and have at most 7 digits after the decimal at Function.createAccount (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/stellar-base/lib/operations/create_account.js:34:11)
    at main (/home/ubuntu/workspace/users.js:35:40)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7) , you why i'm having this one ??

Comment: PS: Both accounts are funded now using stellar laboratory

Comment: You have to put the amount in quotes to declare it as a String, it's considered a numeric value otherwise. { startingAmount: '10' ... }